# What is the Twilio URL parameter?

Tags: python, twilio

I am trying to write a Twilio script to make a call in Python. I am trying to follow [the documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/python/rest/call-request), but am baffled by the `url` parameter.

The example [the documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/python/rest/call-request) supplies is as follows:

```
from twilio.rest import TwilioRestClient

account_sid = "ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
auth_token = "YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY"
client = TwilioRestClient(account_sid, auth_token)

call = client.calls.create(to="+14085551234",  # Any phone number
                           from_="+12125551234", # Must be a valid Twilio number
                           url="http://twimlets.com/holdmusic?Bucket=com.twilio.music.ambient")
print call.sid
```

What is the `url` parameter doing here? Should I copy it or supply my own URL? Does that mean I have to write my own endpoint?

The documentation on URL parameter is not much more enlightening: https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls#url-parameter

Please could someone explain what this is, and whether I need to change it or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Url parameter determines what is heard on the call when the phone is answered.  This is customizable using TwiML (Twilio Markup Language) a set of roughly a dozen XML tags, which your application should return at the specified url.  The XML your application returns at the Url decides how to handle the call, for example whether to forward the call to another line, speak some words or send an SMS reply.  You can read a bit more about TwiML here:

https://twilio.radicalskills.com/projects/getting-started-with-twiml/2.html